# how to make background image to cover size

Tags: html, css

how can we make an image a cover size if we are using

HTML

```
 <div class="image">
  <img src="some image"/>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .image{
   height:300px;
   width:100%;
 }
 .image img{
   background-size:cover;
 }
```

Comment: you can't use `background-size: cover;` for the `img` inside the `div`. But you can remove the `img`, and use the source as a background image in the `div.image` by using this `CSS`: `background: url(some_image_url);`

Comment: There's like "a lot" of questions already made and answered about this topic in stackoverflow. It's recomended to check around before making a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code...

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more info [Refer](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

CSS code:

```
  .image{ 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the below code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="some image"/>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .image img{
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size:cover;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/backround.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

EDIT : This is responsive

Note this only works for 
Safari 3+
Chrome (all)
IE 9+
Firefox 3.6+